# Dynamically change border color of selectized option

Tags: javascript, css, selectize.js

I am using **selectized.js** on my Select tag to add searchability. My problem is the validation of selectize. I wanted to change the border color to red of a selected when there is no selected value. I tried to add a class that have red border but it is not working. Is there a way to change the color of the border?

```
<select class="rui-selectize-element rui-selectize-select" id="finasst">
    <option value="0">FALSE</option>
    <option value="1">TRUE</option>
</select>
```

for example

```
var finasst = $("#finasst").val();

if(finasst == ''){
   //add classe to change color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by making the default border color of the select element red and making javascript funtion to remove the color when changing the select option, this can be done by chaning the html code to be as follow:

```
<select class="rui-selectize-element rui-selectize-select" id="finasst" style="border: solid red" onchange="border_change();">
<option value="0">FALSE</option>
<option value="1">TRUE</option></select>
```

and add the javascript function as follow:

```
function border_change(){
var select_element = document.getElementById("finasst");
if(select_element.selectedIndex>=0)
    select_element.style.borderColor = "";}
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Here it is code snippet for my code:

```js
function border_change(){
    var select_element = document.getElementById("finasst");
    if(select_element.selectedIndex>=0)
        select_element.style.borderColor = "";
}
```

```html
<select class="rui-selectize-element rui-selectize-select" id="finasst" style="border: solid red" onchange="border_change();">
    <option value="0">FALSE</option>
    <option value="1">TRUE</option>
</select>
```

If it is not working,please give me more details for your requirements.

Comment: it does not changed the border color of my selectized

Comment: What is the color of the border that you need when selecting an option? Also does the inline style of the select does not change the default border color to red using my code after you tested it?